# Como forçar um drop table no SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ao tentar dar um `drop table` em uma tabela que possui relacionamentos, ocorre o seguinte erro: `#1451 - Não pode apagar uma linha pai: uma restrição de chave estrangeira falhou`

> Existe algum modo de forçar a exclusão da tabela sem ter que apagar os
>   relacionamentos?

Comment: Você quer dropar uma tabela onde existem vários relacionamentos? Qual o motivo disto?

Comment: Correto @Marconi sei que vai dar erros em outros lugares, mas no momento eu preciso dropar esta tabela.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O código abaixo desativa a verificação por chaves estrangeiras, com ela desativada, tu pode deletar qualquer tabela com relacionamento, nota que as verificações devem ser acionadas posteriormente p/ manter a integridade das estruturas.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
-- Drop tables
drop table ...
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Encontrei essa *alternativa* [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300396/force-drop-mysql-bypassing-foreign-key-constraint), acredito que seja o que procura.

Answer (score 3):

Faça deste modo:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
Drop table ...
```

O `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` vai remover a verificação da chave estrangeira.

Lembre de retornar a verificação ao valor original com `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`